# $\nabla g\cdot\hat{r}=\frac{\partial g}{\partial r}$ (polar coordinates)

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$$\nabla g\cdot\hat{r}=\frac{\partial g}{\partial r}$$

I just want to check whether my understanding of $\nabla g\cdot\hat{r}=\frac{\partial g}{\partial r}$ is correct, where $\nabla g$ is in polar coordinates.

Is it because $$\nabla g=(\frac{\partial g}{\partial r},\frac{\partial g}{\partial\theta})$$, $$\hat{r}=(1,0)$$
thus the conclusion?

Or is there a deeper reason?

Thanks for the enlightenment!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In polar coordinates you have
$$\nabla g = \frac{\partial g}{\partial r} \hat r + \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial g}{\partial \theta } \hat \theta $$
where $\hat r$ and $\hat \theta$ are the unit orthogonal vectors at any point. So you can calculate 
$$\nabla g \cdot \hat r = (\frac{\partial g}{\partial r} \hat r + \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial g}{\partial \theta } \hat \theta)\cdot \hat r$$
$$ = \frac{\partial g}{\partial r} (\hat r \cdot \hat r) + \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial g}{\partial \theta } (\hat \theta \cdot \hat r)$$
$$ =  \frac{\partial g}{\partial r} (1) + \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial g}{\partial \theta } (0)$$
$$ =  \frac{\partial g}{\partial r} $$

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, indeed it helps!